# Shiny app with two sliders: second slider is only selecting the endpoints, not range

Tags: r, shiny

I have written the following `R Shiny` app.  The user selects `farm` from a drop-down menu and a single value of `year` from a `slider`.  I would like the user to be able to select a `range` of values for `month`, but the second `slider` is only selecting the end points of `month`, not the `range`.

Here is what the `month` `slider` is selecting, as an example with `farm == 1` and `year == 2` from the `data.frame fruit` created within the `app` below:

```
> fruit[fruit$farm == 1 & fruit$year == 2 & fruit$month %in% c(4,9),]
   farm year month   apples cherries
16    1    2     4 70.23774 82.18512
21    1    2     9 38.99675 66.07546
```

Here is what I would like the `month` `slider` to select:

```
> fruit[fruit$farm == 1 & fruit$year == 2 & fruit$month %in% c(4:9),]
   farm year month   apples cherries
16    1    2     4 70.23774 82.18512
17    1    2     5 37.17340 83.47027
18    1    2     6 36.00925 73.27322
19    1    2     7 31.20337 98.30440
20    1    2     8 33.93355 63.92046
21    1    2     9 38.99675 66.07546
```

How can I modify this code so all selected months are included in the resulting `plot`?  Here is my `Shiny` app:

```
library(shiny)

set.seed(1234)

n.farms <- 5
n.years <- 3

fruit <- data.frame(
        farm = rep(1:n.farms, each = 12*n.years),
        year = rep(rep(1:n.years, each = 12), n.farms),
       month = rep(1:12,n.farms * n.years),
      apples = runif(n.farms*12*n.years, 20, 80),
    cherries = runif(n.farms*12*n.years, 0, 100)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Subset and Plot Fruit Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("codeInput1", label = "Choose Farm", choices = unique(fruit$farm)),

            sliderInput("codeInput2", label = "Select Year", 
                                      min = min(fruit$year), max = max(fruit$year), 
                                      value = median(fruit$year), step = 1),

            sliderInput("codeInput3", label = "Select Month Range", 
                                      min = min(fruit$month), max = max(fruit$month), 
                                      value = unique(fruit$month)[c(4,9)], step = 1)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("view")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset <- reactive({
        return(subset(fruit, (farm   ==  input$codeInput1 & 
                              year   ==  input$codeInput2 & 
                              month %in% input$codeInput3)))
    })

    output$view <- renderPlot(plot(dataset()$apples, dataset()$cherries))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select a range, `sliderInput` returns the minimum and the maximum, but not all values in this range. So you have to generate the range from the two returned values:

```
month %in% (input$codeInput3[1]:input$codeInput3[2])
```

**Edit**

As Mark points out, my solution only works for integers; the correct way to test for a range (with included borders) is:

```
month >= input$codeInput3[1] && month <= input$codeInput3[2]
```

Comment: Your answer worked in this case but not in a subsequent case in which I was told I needed to use: `(month >= input$codeInput3[1] & month <= input$codeInput3[2])`.  Your answer probably is fine in this case because `month` is an integer.