# R Shiny app with slider not selecting all values in specified range

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an `R Shiny` app in which a user selects two variables `period` and `unit` from drop down menus, a single value of a third variable `x` using a `slider`, and a `range` of values for a fourth variable `y` using a `slider`.  The app should `plot` two other variables (`apples` and `cherries`) from the selected lines of data.

I create a data set within the app and an example set of selected lines are:

```
#    period unit    x      y    apples  cherries
#127      1    1 0.05 -0.005 -131570.5 -23648402
#217      1    1 0.05 -0.003 -107586.8  -7777483
```

However, the app appears to be plotting only a single point in this example.  I asked an earlier question today using a simpler example.  The posted answer worked with that other data set, but does not seem to work with this slightly more complex current data set.

[Shiny app with two sliders: second slider is only selecting the endpoints, not range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265345/shiny-app-with-two-sliders-second-slider-is-only-selecting-the-endpoints-not-r)

I might be making a really simple typo somewhere.  Although the structure of the current code appears to be the same as the structure of the code used in my earlier example.  Thank you for any help.

Here is my app and the resulting plot:

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(1234)

n.periods <- 6
n.units   <- 3

policy.data <- expand.grid(period = c(1:n.periods), unit = c(1:n.units), 
               x = seq(0.01,0.09,0.02), y = seq(-0.007,-0.001,0.002))
policy.data <- data.frame(policy.data)
policy.data$apples   <- rnorm(nrow(policy.data), mean = -100000, sd = 50000)
policy.data$cherries <- rnorm(nrow(policy.data), mean = -10000000, sd = 5000000)

policy.data[policy.data$period == 1 & policy.data$unit == 1 & 
            policy.data$x == 0.05 & policy.data$y %in% c(-0.005,-0.003),]
#    period unit    x      y    apples  cherries
#127      1    1 0.05 -0.005 -131570.5 -23648402
#217      1    1 0.05 -0.003 -107586.8  -7777483

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Subsetting Policy Dataset"),
        p("Base = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("codeInput1", label = "Choose Period", choices = unique(policy.data$period)),
            selectInput("codeInput2", label = "Choose Unit",   choices = unique(policy.data$unit)),
            sliderInput("codeInput3", label = "x", min = min(policy.data$x), max = max(policy.data$x), 
                        value = median(policy.data$x),         step = unique(round(diff(unique(policy.data$x)),2))),
            sliderInput("codeInput4", label = "y", min = min(policy.data$y), max = max(policy.data$y), 
                        value = unique(policy.data$y)[c(2,3)], step = unique(round(diff(unique(policy.data$y)),3)))

        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("view")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset <- reactive({
        return(subset(policy.data, (period == input$codeInput1 & unit == input$codeInput2 &
                                    x      == input$codeInput3 & 
                                    y     %in% (input$codeInput4[1]:input$codeInput4[2]))))
    })

    output$view <- renderPlot(plot(dataset()$apples, dataset()$cherries))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a range for y you should use > and <, and not %in%.

```
y <- 0.5
# is y between 0 and 1?
y> 0 & y <1 #True
y %in% 0:1  #False because 0:1 = c(0,1) and 0.5 isn't equal to 0 or 1
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: So in this case I should use: `(y >= input$codeInput4[1] & y <= input$codeInput4[2])`?